# Automação de cadastros (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, pessoal!

Estou com um problema e preciso da ajuda de vocês para bolar uma solução.
Minha situação é a seguinte: Existe uma página .php que vai ser acessada diariamente por várias pessoas, essa página vai executar um script .sql e retornar um valor... Só que aí é onde está o problema...

Preciso criar um sistema de fila de espera, algo assim, porque o .sql não pode ser executado ao mesmo tempo por várias pessoas.

Alguma ideia de como prosseguir?
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce precisa criar uma tabela no DB chamada fila com os valores dos usuarios e o campo espera de valor 1 e 0 por ordem de chegada.

Antes do usuario usar o seu script ele entra nessa tabela com o valor 0, se ele for o primeiro da lista o valor dele sera 1 e ele usara o script. Apos o uso ele tem que ser deletado desta tabela.

Além disso os usuarios que estao em espera tem que ser informados disso em uma pagina e esta pagina tem que ter um auto refresh a cada 1 minuto por exemplo para que seja feito uma nova verificaçao no banco de dados

Veja a tabela:

**fila**

> id,
>   email, espera

**verificar.php**

```
    <?php 


    // verifica se existe algum usuário usando o sistema 
    $selecionaUsuariosUsandoSistema = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fila WHERE espera = 1");

    // verifica se existe algum usuário na fila
    $selecionaUsuariosEspera = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fila WHERE espera = 0");

    if(mysql_num_rows($selecionaUsuariosUsandoSistema) == 0 && mysql_num_rows($selecionaUsuariosEspera) == 0){

        // se não existir o usuario usando o sistema ou na fila, ele será inserido no banco de dados depois redirecionado direto para o sistema

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO fila(id, email, espera) VALUES (0, '$emailUsuario', 1)");

        header("Location: diretoParaOScript.php");

    } else {

        // se existir algum usuario na fila ou no sistema ele sera inserido no banco de dados com valor 0 e redirecionado para página espera.php

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO fila(id, email, espera) VALUES (0, '$emailUsuario', 0)");

        header("Location: espera.php");

    }

    ?>
```

**espera.php**

```
   <?php

$selecionaUsuariosEspera = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM fila ORDER BY id");
$usuariosEmEspera = mysql_fetch_array($selecionaUsuariosEspera);

$emailUsuario = 'fulano@ciclano.com.br';

//verifica se o email do usuário é o próximo da fila

if($emailUsuario == $usuariosEmEspera[0]){
    //se for o próximo, ele edita o valor do usuário para 1 e redireciona para o sistema
    mysql_query("UPDATE fila SET espera = '1' WHERE email = '$emailUsuario'");

    header("Location: diretoParaOScript.php");

} else {


   ?>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
    </head>
   <body>

aguarde...

    </body>
    </html>

   <?php } ?>
```

Depois que o usuário fechar o sistema ele tem que ser deletado da tabela

Outras considerações...

Criei este método para dar uma luz para você, pois não sei como funciona o seu sistema.

você tem que considerar algumas coisas como:

- E se o usuário fechar o navegador antes de usar o sistema, vai parar a fila?
- talvez métodos com cookies e outras sessions sejam necessários para verificar se o usuário está acessando o sistema, se ele ainda está na fila e descartá-lo se não.

boa sorte

Comment: Entendi Andrei, achei a sua solução muito boa, a ideia de criar uma db para a fila de espera e tudo mais. Na verdade eu só estou analisando a lógica mesmo, ainda não decidi em qual linguagem vou fazer o código. Muito obrigado! Era isso que eu precisava ;)

Comment: Tranquilo @Wesley, não esqueça de aprovar a resposta se te ajudou. =) abraço